# How to replace all NaT and nan in df with None

Tags: python, google-bigquery

How can I replace all NaT and NaN values with None.

Reason being is that I am using insert_rows_from_dataframe from BigQuery and it can not handle NaN and NaT

Comment: Look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Yes but when I put value=None, nothing happens. Only when I specify a certain scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use df.replace
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html
Pass a list containing the value to be replaced as the first argument, and a list containing `None` as the second argument.

```
df.replace([float('nan')], [None])
```

This will indicate to the function that you intend `None` as the replacement value, rather than not providing and argument.